# Inserting/Adding Column totals (sum) at the bottom of the table after a PIVOT

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, pivot, crosstab

I really need your help to accomplish adding a separate new row to my table after running a PIVOT command (Crosstab Query).

My objective is to count the column totals of each of the [Request Types] and insert the sum of the column into a new row at the bottom of my table.

This seems like rocket science to me and is above and beyond my capabilities and knowledge of the SQL language/realm.

Here's a quick screenshot of the data in my table:

[image]

Here is a quick screenshot of the data captured from the table after running a CrossTab Query of TableA

```
TRANSFORM Count([Division]) AS CountOfDivision
SELECT [Branch], [Division]
FROM TableA
GROUP BY [Branch], [Division]
PIVOT [Request Type]
```

[image]

Here is the desired result/expected outcome of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: Without giving the answer away, I'll give you a hint:  UNION

Comment: I'm totally lost as it is and ready to pull all of my hair out. I've been googling for hours in search of an answer. Can this even be done? Where would you stick the Union query and how does it fit in?

Comment: Yes it can be done.  Search for UNION on here, or Google.  It works by taking two different queries (with the same columns *important*) and sicks the second query on the bottom of the first.

Comment: How would a Union be able count the column once the [Request Types] have  been transposed to rows?

Comment: Because you're going to union the same query in the bottom part - but it will be a sub query with a parent aggregate...

I'm limited to using SQL Server, and I'm writing a different way to accomplish this, but using the same idea of the UNION...  There are many different ways to do this, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in a comment to the original post, I am limited to using SQL Server and not MS Access.  However, the suggestion was to use a UNION statement in the query for MS Access - which this example still provides a valid way to answer the question.

To create a "Total" line below all of the individual records, an aggregate query needs to be written using the same SQL (with the addition of aggregate functions to the columns to be 'totaled).

I am using `CASE` statements here to make the logic a little simpler to digest without the added complexity of a cross-tab and pivot.

```
SELECT   A.Branch
        ,A.Division
        ,CASE WHEN A.RequestType = 'Report' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Report
        ,CASE WHEN A.RequestType = 'Financial Analysis' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FinancialAnalysis
        ,CASE WHEN A.RequestType = 'Letter' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Letter
        ,CASE WHEN A.RequestType = 'Research Paper' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ResearchPaper
  FROM   TableA

UNION

SELECT   'TOTAL'
        ,NULL
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN A.RequestType = 'Report' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Report
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN A.RequestType = 'Financial Analysis' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FinancialAnalysis
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN A.RequestType = 'Letter' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Letter
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN A.RequestType = 'Research Paper' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ResearchPaper
  FROM   TableA
```

The results of this query will look like this:

```
Branch  Division    Report  FinancialAnalysis   Letter  ResearchPaper
ASFA    ASFAA       1       0                   0       0
ASFA    ASFAB       1       0                   0       0
ASFA    ASFAD       0       0                   0       1
ASFB    ASFBE       0       0                   1       0
ASFC    ASFCC       0       1                   0       0
TOTAL   NULL        2       1                   1       1
```

This works by taking all of the tabulated columns form the first query and querying them a second time, but also adding them up.  This produces only a single row - which is appended to the first query.

When using MS Access, the `CASE` statement I've used above will not work unless you're coding this logic in VBA, and even then the syntax is different.  The SQL code in MS access will need to use the `SWITCH` or `IIF` functions instead